# set amazon firetv backlight programmatically via adb

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv, backlight

Is it possible to set the backlight or brightness of an amazon firetv programmatically via adb?

After searching on the amazon firetv app store there appears to be an [app](https://www.amazon.com/s?i=mobile-apps&rh=p_4%3AOleksii%20Ustenko&search-type=ss) that is capable of updating the backlight and brightness, so I assume there must be an android/firetv API to do so. Is there a way to achieve this using an adb command?

Answer (score 0):

It should work with

```
adb shell settings put system screen_brightness <VALUE>
```

Comment: I tried this, the setting appears to be applied successfully but there is no change in the screen brightness.